# How can I get kernel 3.7.1 header files in Ubuntu 16.04 x32?

Tags: apt, kernel, ppa

I am now doing some kernel exploit stuff and I have to build kernel module with kernel 3.7.1 header files.I google a lot but can't find these two files below

https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.7.1-raring/linux-headers-3.7.1-030701-generic_3.7.1-030701.201212171620_i386.deb

https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.7.1-raring/linux-headers-3.7.1-030701_3.7.1-030701.201212171620_all.deb

Anyone can upload these files here or show the download URL.Thanks!

Comment: You haven't said for what OS/release you want them, however those kernels are way past EOL, unsupported and were only ever for testing.  No Ubuntu release used them, so they're likely not kept.

Comment: I am on ubuntu 16.04 32 bit.I know they are unsupported but I have to write CTF solution through 3.7.1 header files.

Answer (score 0):

This answer shows how version 3.7.1 might be found under a different numbering scheme:

- [Install linux headers 3.7 on debian 8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214385/install-linux-headers-3-7-on-debian-8)

In this case the equivalent kernel version for Debian was `linux-headers-3.16.0.4-all`.

In Ubuntu the `3.16` equivalent would probably best be found by matching up the published dates in the Ubuntu Mainline Kernel page you already linked.

Answer (score 0):

The first of the files you've requested has been stored by the Wayback Machine:

[https://web.archive.org/web/20170927195456/http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.7.1-raring/linux-headers-3.7.1-030701-generic_3.7.1-030701.201212171620_i386.deb](https://web.archive.org/web/20170927195456/http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v3.7.1-raring/linux-headers-3.7.1-030701-generic_3.7.1-030701.201212171620_i386.deb)

The second file, unfortunately, hasn't been archived.

Also, WinEunuuchs2Unix's answer seems completely unrelated to your question, but hopefully that's just me misunderstanding it.